# What are the vimscript delete() function return codes and their meanings?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

In vimscript there is a function to delete a file from disk. The [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#delete()) says that a 0 return code means success, and non-zero indicates a failure. Does anyone know what the different non-zero values mean? Specifically, I'm using Christian Brabrandt's [Recover.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/Recover.vim) plugin. (I will create an issue in his repo, by the way.) At one point in its processing, it attempts to delete the swap file, but the delete() function is returning a -2. I'm using the `set directory=...` option in my vimrc, and I have read/write access to the swap file folder, and vim itself will create and delete swap files just fine. I suspect there may be a problem with the way the filename is escaped before passing it to the delete function.

Comment: Looking at the sources, `delete()` can only return 0 and -1, never -2. :)

Comment: My apologies. I also have NeoVim installed, and that is where the -2 comes from. Which source code file contains the delete function? I'll take a look at it.

Comment: The function is `f_delete()` in `src/eval.c` in Vim.  It calls `unlink()`, which returns error codes in `errno` but `f_delete()` happily ignores that.  As far as I can tell, the same function is handled by LUA's `os.remove()` in neovim.  You don't get any meaningful return code from that, either.

Comment: Thanks for looking that up.